# OpenCV functions won't work on OpenCV window converted in PyQt GUI window

Tags: python, qt, opencv, image-processing, pyqt

I am using OpenCV for image processing and embedding the images in a PyQt GUI window. I have used the OpenCV code independently and it works fine. I can also create the following windows and objects in OpenCV and successfully convert them other color spaces via cv2.cvtColor then convert to QPixmap and display them.

The problem arises when I try to do anything to the OpenCV image other than converting color spaces. I've tried simple OpenCV operations such a cv.Smooth and even creating a threshold image using cv.CreateImage and none of these work. I'm not sure if it's taking to long to perform these operations and the QTGui is timing out. 
Please help me, I don't understand what's wrong. I've provided snippets of my code below:

```
import cv2    
import cv2.cv as cv
import numpy as np
import from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Video():
    def __init__(self,capture):
        self.capture = capture
        self.capture.open(1)
        self.currentFrame=np.array([])
        self.capture.set(3,800)
        self.capture.set(4,600)
        self.capture.set(5,30)

    def processImage(self):
        try:
            while(True):
                ret, readFrame=self.capture.read() # Grab next frame
                if(ret==True):
                    print "processImage grabbed a frame"

                    #readFrame=cv2.cvtColor(readFrame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) < -- This works fine
                    #readFrame=cv2.cvtColor(readFrame,cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB) < -- This works fine
                    cv.Smooth(readFrame,readFrame,cv.CV_BLUR,3) < -- Any functions like this cause problems
                    print 'It made it this far' # < -- This never gets printed because cv.Smooth doesn't properly execute
        except TypeError:
            print "ERROR: processImage couldn't get a frame"

        def convertFrame(self):
    """     converts frame to format suitable for QtGui            """
        try:
            height,width=self.currentFrame.shape[:2]
            img=QtGui.QImage(self.currentFrame,width,height,QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
            img=QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(img)
            self.previousFrame = self.currentFrame
            return img
        except:
            return None
```

I have even tried to use cv.Smooth then use cv2.cvtColor to convert to RGB to QT Gui and it doesn't matter; once it hits the cv.Smooth or any other OpenCV function other than cvtColor it doesn't go past it.

Here is the code for the GUI:

```
class Gui(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.video = Video(cv2.VideoCapture()) # Which device to capture frames from
        self._timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self._timer.timeout.connect(self.play)
        self._timer.start(27)
        self.update()

    def play(self):
        try:
            self.video.processImage()
            self.ui.videoFrame.setPixmap(self.video.convertFrame())
            self.ui.videoFrame.setScaledContents(True)
        except TypeError:
            print "No frame"

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Gui()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Could it be something to do with the Qt GUI calling on processImage() and it taking to long to process the images and timing out by going on to the next call of processImage() before the previous function returns?

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody even attempted to answer this, really? Well if you ever are in this situation and need to figure it out, here is the solution to the problem:

1. Always use the cv2 class instead of the old cv class.
2. In my code I was trying to use cv.QueryFrame which returns a cvMat and pyqt does not like this data type for some reason.
3. You need to convert all of the old cv functions over to the new cv2 functions. Calling capture.read() instead of cv.QueryFrame(capture) returns a VideoCapture object and this is a data type that pyqt can deal with.
4. It is a bit of a chore finding out what corresponding function uses cv2 but once you get it working, it's worth it.